# Floating point exception

Tags: c, floating-point

I successfully  complied this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int q;

int main()
{
    srand( time(NULL) );
    int n=3;
    q=ceil(sqrt(n));
    printf("%d\n %d\n", n,q);

    if(n == 2)
        printf("%d\n is prime", n);
    else if(n % 2 == 0.0 || n < 2)
        printf("%d\n is not prime", n);
    else
    {
        int x;
        for(x = 0; x < q; x++){
            if(n % x == 0)
            {
                printf("%d\n is not prime", n);
                return;
            }
            else
                printf("%d\n is prime", n);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run my code I get the following error:

> Floating point exception

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122172/c-programming-floating-point-exception

Answer (score 31):

It's caused by `n % x`, when `x` is 0.  You should have x start at 2 instead. You should not use floating point here at all, since you only need integer operations.

General notes:

1. Try to format your code better.  Focus on using a consistent style.  E.g. you have one else that starts immediately after a if brace (not even a space), and another with a newline in between.
2. Don't use globals unless necessary.  There is no reason for `q` to be global.
3. Don't return without a value in a non-void (int) function.

Comment: Addition: You get a *Floating point exception* since your computer does not have a special case for *integer division by 0*. A better description would be *Arithmetic exception*, but this misnomer has a long history and probably cannot be changed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGFPE

This should give you a really good idea. Since a modulus is, in its basic sense, division with a remainder, `something % 0` IS division by zero and as such, will trigger a SIGFPE being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by `n % x` where `x = 0` in the first loop iteration. You can't calculate a modulus with respect to 0.