# Properly use an argv entry as a variable in another function

Tags: c

I am writing a program where I pass the first argument (argv[1]) which determines the amount of threads I want to use to run a function. I made a global variable called THREAD_COUNT, which is takes place in  argv[1] and converts it to a integer with atoi().

I then want to use that thread_count variable to use as a divisor in a for loop which represent the amount of threads I want to use.

I can't seem to get this right,  as my logic doesnt work and I get a floating point exception.  Would I have to make a pointer out of something?

Go easy on me, I am a begginer programmer and I never used C before.

The code below is for 2 and 4 threads, just ignore the `FUNCTION` variable.

```
#include <"transact.h">
#include <pthread.h>


int balance = 100000000;
int THREAD_COUNT;
int FUNCTION;

void * process(void * arg) {

for(int i = 0; i < 100000000/THREAD_COUNT; i++) {

int transaction = getTransaction(i);

balance = balance - 1;

printf("%d : %d\n", i, transaction);

      } 

}



int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

int THREAD_COUNT = atoi(argv[1]);

int FUNCTION = atoi(argv[2]);


if (THREAD_COUNT == 2 && FUNCTION == 0) {

pthread_t thread1, thread2;

pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, process, NULL);

pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, process, NULL);

pthread_join(thread1, NULL);

pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

printf("Balance is: %d \n", balance);

}
else if (THREAD_COUNT == 4 && FUNCTION == 0){

pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4;

pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, process, NULL);

pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, process, NULL);

pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, process, NULL);

pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, process, NULL);

pthread_join(thread1, NULL);

pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

pthread_join(thread3, NULL);

pthread_join(thread4, NULL);

}

else {

printf("Enter 2, 4, 8 \n ");

}

}
```

Comment: Floating point exceptions occur when dividing by zero - more reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122172/c-programming-floating-point-exception

Comment: Typo in your 4-thread block - it calls ```pthread_create(&thread3, ....)``` twice - should be ```&thread4```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have both a *global* variable named `THREAD_COUNT`, with an undefined value, and then a *local* variable named `THREAD_COUNT` in your `main` function which shadows the global variable.

That means the global `THREAD_COUNT` never gets set, so you're probably dividing by 0.

You need to modify the beginning of your `main` function to look like:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    THREAD_COUNT = atoi(argv[1]);
    FUNCTION = atoi(argv[2])

    ...
}
```

By not re-declaring the variables, this sets the global vars, rather than setting a local variable of the same name.

---

Also note that with your current code, if you forget to pass cli arguments it will fail with a segmentation fault (because it will call `atoi` with a null value). You might want to protect against that.

Comment: Global variables are always initialized to 0 if they don't have an explicit initializer.

Comment: Im not sure if you seen the else statment since I forgot to add that portion of code and was editing my post rapidly, but is that else statement fine?  Also thanks for the help, I cant believe I over sought that redeclaring variable in my main.

Comment: If your question is, "does that `else` statement protect me if the program is run with no parameters?", the answer is no, because `atoi()` is called outside of your `if` statement. If the question is, "is that `else` statement syntactically correct?", the answer is sure, it looks fine.