# When computing the sum of the series [1-X^2/2!+X^4/4!- ...] why is the output showing "-1.00" for every input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main() {

    int n;
    int x;
    printf("enter base");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("number of tearms");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    float sum=1.00;
    int fact=1;
    int s=1;
    int p=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        s =s*(-1);
        int z=2*i;
        p =pow(x,z);
        fact =fact*2*i*(2*i-1);
        int k=s*p/fact;
        sum =sum+k;
    }
    printf("the sum is : %0.2f",sum);
}
```

The logic and everything is correct, but I don't know why the output is getting an error. after getting some feedbacks i rectified some errors. now the out put is showing -1.00 for every input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C programming - floating point exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122172/c-programming-floating-point-exception)

Comment: how can `pow(x,2i)` work?

Comment: You won 't sum many terms correctly using `int fact` which will soon overflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `s*p/fact` all are ints, so this term will be calculated using integer arithmetic, then added to sum.

Comment: Clang 8.0 accepts `2i` as a floating point literal (and treats it as `0`). Can anyone explain that?  https://ideone.com/4s1a40

Comment: @persixty: why does it need explanation? It's in the GCC manual under C extensions, and Clang implements most GCC extensions.

Comment: @rici Because I couldn't find in the manual. If it's not in the top 3 results in Google. It needs explanation.

Comment: @Persixty: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Complex.html. (It was the sixth result in the search I did, but customization of Google results means that "top 3 results" is relative.)

Comment: @rici Where's the bit where it casts that back to a `double`? That's the problem here. Or the library function `pow(int,complex)`?

Comment: @persixty: C standard, Conversions (6.3.1.7/2): "When a value of complex type is converted to a real type other than bool, the imaginary part of the complex value is discarded and the value of the real part is converted according to the conversion rules for the corresponding real type."

Comment: @persixty: The library function is `pow(double, double)` unless you `#include <tgmath.h>`. With tgmath, though, you'll get an ambiguous prototype compile-time error (at least on GCC).

Comment: @rici It's not clear what the OP used. But I don't understand why it accepts a complex number and just knocks off the imaginary part. Seems very sloppy though I'm aware GCC is very sloppy without the right settings.

Comment: @persixty: If it's sloppy, then the sloppiness is in the C standard, not GCC. Did you not read my comment quoting the standard?

Comment: @rici No I didn't. Yes they're both sloppy and this question is an example of why such sloppiness bad. The C standard has gone through some bad times. :(

Comment: @Persixty: You're entitled to your opinion, of course. But how is it different from silently discarding the fraction from a floating point number when converted to an `int`? (Rhetorical question, really. C conversions have lots of potential issues, such as the classic `signed_integer < unsigned_integer` fiasco. You just have to be aware of them.)

Comment: @rici How is that sloppiness different from all the other sloppiness that causes endless problems. In some ways it's not. But the sloppiness you refer to is sloppiness that existed when the language was standardised in hindsight. 
We should expect later extensions like complex numbers to be cleaner. I wasn't aware it so readily discarded the imaginary part but that's a good reason for not using them in anger.

Comment: @persixty: In defense of GCC (and Clang), if you add `-Wconversion` to the command line, the compiler will warn you about both `int x = pow(b, e);` and `double x = pow(b, 2i);`, the first because the fraction is being dropped (in the assignment); the second because the imaginary part is being dropped (in the conversion of the parameter `2i`). Also, `-Wpedantic` will warn you about the use of Gnu extensions like `2i` (standard is `2*I` after `#include <complex.h>` to define `I`.) So if you ask the compiler for help, it will. (But `-Wall` isn't really "all".) https://godbolt.org/z/3cWfrsjoW

Comment: @rici But it remains sloppy that the C Standard just ditches the imaginary part. Even though we all know that it is so easy to accidentally pass a complex value to a function expecting double. Like bit-fields I've ignored complex numbers because they're not good extensions. Throw them on the pile of things C never needed and you don't either.

Comment: @Persixty: To each their own. I use both bitfields and complex numbers, and find them useful for things they are useful for. But that's me. I'm not preaching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify 17 or more terms your factorial (`fact`) eventually overflows to 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {;
    int fact=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=17;i++) {
        fact =fact*2*i*(2*i-1);
        printf("%d: %d\n",i,fact);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Typical output on platform using 32-bit integers:

```
1: 2
2: 24
3: 720
4: 40320
5: 3628800
6: 479001600
7: 1278945280
8: 2004189184
9: -898433024
10: -2102132736
11: -522715136
12: -775946240
13: -1853882368
14: -1375731712
15: 1409286144
16: -2147483648
17: 0
```

Change all your integer variables to `double`. Don't bother with `float` unless you have a specific reason (most likely space). It's a bit of an artefact and you should default to `double` in modern code.

Here's such a version. 20 terms for x=10.0 is `0.84` which is a fair approximation for COS(10.0) [what you wanted I assume!!]

I've output the terms to show convergence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    int n;
    int x;
    printf("enter base");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("number of terms");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    double sum=1.00;
    double fact=1.0;
    double s=1.0;
    double p=1.0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        s=s*(-1.0);
        p=pow(x,2*i);
        fact =fact*2.0*i*(2.0*i-1.0);
        double term=s*p/fact;
        printf("%d: %f\n",i,term);
        sum =sum+term;
    }
    printf("the sum is : %0.2f",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My suggestion: rather than using `pow` and the auxiliary variable `s`, just do `p *= -x*x;`

Comment: @rici A worthwhile suggestion. I'd start with making `x`  `double` before that. I don't think answers should make too many auxiliary suggests. My bonus here is to ditch `float`.

Comment: You also changed `p` from `int` to `double` which avoids the usual problem with trying to do integer powers (truncation a very slightly incorrect result to the result minus one). I would have preferred the incremental multiply option in order to retain integer arithmetic, although there are obvious issues with integer overflow, as you note, which could be ameliorated by using `long long`.

Comment: @rici But I don't think the OP really wants integer arithmetic. It's the Taylor Series for Cos(X). Which is a reason for not making 'too many' corrections. You think OP wants to calculate Cos(x) for integer x and I think x being int is another error because it would normally be floating-point.

Comment: I agree with that, to be sure. I don't know what OP's intent was; I just read the code.

Comment: @rici Unquestionably calculating Cos(x). See third line: https://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I assume your `pow` function is from the standard `<cmath>` header?  (the #include isn't listed in your snippet).  Also - it would be helpful to list your full build command line and example user inputs for which you see the error.

The problem is most probably in `pow(x,2i)`, but in C++20 it should have manifested as a compile error, not runtime one. In clang it is:

```
error: implicit conversion from '_Complex int' to 'double' is not permitted in C++
        p =pow(x,2i);
```

and in gcc:

```
error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""i'
   21 |         p =pow(x,2i);
```

Comment: The question is about C, not C++.

Comment: MSVC C compiler simply says for `2i` *syntax error: 'bad suffix on number'*.

Comment: [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/1UAYmh), using GCC 8.3 says this is valid syntax.  But I have no idea how its interpreting it.

Comment: @abelenky It interprets `2i` as a `_Complex int`. In other words, `2 * √-1`.