# checking for co-prime in C prgramming language

Tags: c, math

```
#include <stdio.h>

int iscoprime(int num1, int num2);

int main() {

    int x;
    x = iscoprime( 7, 8 );
    printf("%d",x);a
}

int iscoprime(int num1, int num2) {

    int r = 0;
    int gcd = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; (i < num1) || (i < num2) ; ++i) {

        if( (num1 % i == 0) && (num2 % i == 0)) {

            gcd = i;
        }
    }

    if ( gcd == 1 ) r = 1;
    return r;
}
```

Error: this program has stopped..??? :(

Comment: `% i` ==> `% 0`, `i = 0` should be `i = 1`

Comment: does your code aim to find the gcd or whether the numbers are co-prime or not?

Comment: Assuming this is homework, were you not given a description of the algorithm normally used to find the gcd (greatest common divisor)? Also were you not told if two numbers are coprime, then their gcd is 1? You can find out this information doing a search on wikipedia or other sites.

Comment: This was my first question.. and i was trying to learn how to use this site whenever i need help.. some developers considered as the silly questions and downvoted it and now i am blocked of asking any question for days... please upvote it guys.. I am learning development on my own.. and i need help from you guys..

Answer (score 2):

Your program has some flaws.

1) The `for` loop starts with `i` value 0. So, in the first iteration itself, [floating point exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615476/floating-point-exception) will occur. It should start from `1`.

2) Your question stated that the program is finding the `gcd`. Which doesn't seem to be the matter. It seems to me that it is finding whether the given numbers are co-prime or not.

If its a GCD program, the `return` statement should be

```
return gcd; //without the previous if condition
```

Comment: yes.. the main working of the program was to find if the two numbers are co primes or not... my bad.. but it was my first question on any forum asking for help on my program so i just typed whatever was being accepted in title without thinking... and Thanks!! :) i realized where were flaws in my program.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what you want your return value to mean from the iscoprime function. It looks like it returns the greatest common divisor and then checks if it is 1, then the two inputs are co-prime, and else it uses r's initial value of 0 hence meaning it will print 1 if the numbers are co-prime and 0 if they are not. Your for loop doesn't quite make sense. The max greatest common divisor of two numbers can have would be the lower of the two values. I would start your for loop at this value, 7 in your case and decrement i with each iteration and return i when both numbers divide by i without a remainder. This would would then be your greatest common divisor, if it is 1, then your two numbers are co-prime.

While this implementation is fine for small numbers, if the numbers are going to be very large, I would have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm which can compute the GCD very fast and the same will still apply, if the GCD is 1, the two inputs are co-prime.